# How to Pass on User Events to Another View after processing it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

Say I have a UITableview.

If user click on a table cell the cell is selected.

The same way I have MKMapView. If a user select an annotation than the annotation is selected.

Now I want to arrange that something happened when I click an empty part of the cell.

So I add a tap gesture.

But then when I click, the non empty part of the cell, like the table, and stuff, the cell and mapview don't get selected again.

Only the gesture selector get called.

After the gesture selector is called I want to "pass" the tab back to table cell and mkmapview. How would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Call your code in the `touchesEnded` method of your subclass and then call `touchesEnded` on the superclass, or called it on a specific view object:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self someMethod];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self someMethod];
    [mapView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```